# Count Substrings of a String

Tags: excel, vba

I have a small macro that creates all the possible ordered substrings of an input string.  So if the input string is :

abcd

the 10 substrings are:

a
ab
abc
abcd
b
bc
bcd
c
cd
d

Is there a formula to calculate the number of substrings from the length of the input string??

Comment: You are looking for Permutation and Combinations

Comment: This question should be moved to mathematics. It has nothing to do with excel-vba.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When n is the length of the string then it's n + (n-1) + (n-2) + ... + 1 = (n+1)*n/2, since the are n substrings of length 1, n-1 substrings of length 2, n-2 substrings of length 3, ..., and 1 substring of length n.

Comment: Hi Christian:  Your answer is just what I need!  I am putting the substrings in an array and can now ReDim that array without a loop counter.  Thanks again.